# Access denied for published code

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, access-denied

I have used the below line to download the temp files in c# mvc

```
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
imgPath = pathDownload + "\\Images\\Img\\Folder1\\";
Directory.CreateDirectory(imgPath);
```

but after hosting it in windows server 2012 i am getting error as Access Denied as "Downloads/Images/Img/Folder1"

I dont know which user it is referring. Please help me to recover this.

Comment: It's likely that whatever identity your application pool uses doesn't have access to create directories in that path. Use a path it does have access to or change your app pool settings.

Comment: you should be able to return your username, so you can display it on some form of debug page and then you can ask for userX to have permissions to folderY

Comment: @Equalsk please suggest me how do i set application pool to have access

Comment: There are countless guides on the internet for setting up application pools with the correct context...